# Error when creating experiment in watson studio

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-studio, ibm-cloud-storage

[image]

I cannot create an experiment within a project nor create a new project because apparently my watson studio doesn't have the right permissions to access/create/delete something in my Cloud object storage instance, knowing that the COS service was created from Watson studio itself.

In case this helps, here is service endpoints information:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions provided in Watson Studio FAQ - https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/getting-started/faq.html#iameditor

Also,Looks like you don’t have proper IAM access permission. If you are the owner of the account, you can set the required permissions following the steps in this [link](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/iam/bp_access.html#account_setup). If you are not the owner ask the account owner for the permissions.

For best practices, refer this [solution tutorial](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/tutorials/users-teams-applications.html#best-practices-for-organizing-users-teams-applications)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need Operator/Editor role. Account owner would need to login into console.bluemix.net and goto "Manage Users" -> https://console.bluemix.net/iam/#/users

1. Cloud Foundry Access -> Space Role -> Add Developer
2. Access Policies -> Assign access to all resources -> Assign platform access roles (Add Operator or above) and Assign service access roles (Add editor or above).

This is only one of the options of setting up user for the things your are trying to do. For more detailed user management, checkout the links that @vidyasagar-machupalli posted in his answer.

[image]
[image]